# Finding true positive / negative and false positive / negative rates using R

Tags: r, roc

I have a data frame with two classes. I want to find the true positive and false positive rate and then plot the ROC curve.

I tried this:

```
new <- data.frame(ytrue=c(1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0),
                  ypred=c(0.98,0.94,0.86,0.74,0.73,0.64,0.53,0.39,0.34,0.31))
new
 ytrue ypred
1      1  0.98
2      0  0.94
3      1  0.86
4      1  0.74
5      0  0.73
6      0  0.64
7      1  0.53
8      0  0.39
9      1  0.34
10     0  0.31

library(ROCR)
pred <- prediction( new$ypred, new$true )
pred
An object of class "prediction"
Slot "predictions":
[[1]]
 [1] 0.98 0.94 0.86 0.74 0.73 0.64 0.53 0.39 0.34 0.31


Slot "labels":
[[1]]
 [1] 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0
Levels: 0 < 1


Slot "cutoffs":
[[1]]
 [1]  Inf 0.98 0.94 0.86 0.74 0.73 0.64 0.53 0.39 0.34 0.31


Slot "fp":
[[1]]
 [1] 0 0 1 1 1 2 3 3 4 4 5


Slot "tp":
[[1]]
 [1] 0 1 1 2 3 3 3 4 4 5 5


Slot "tn":
[[1]]
 [1] 5 5 4 4 4 3 2 2 1 1 0


Slot "fn":
[[1]]
 [1] 5 4 4 3 2 2 2 1 1 0 0


Slot "n.pos":
[[1]]
[1] 5


Slot "n.neg":
[[1]]
[1] 5


Slot "n.pos.pred":
[[1]]
 [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10


Slot "n.neg.pred":
[[1]]
 [1] 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0

perf <- performance( pred, "tpr", "fpr" )
perf
An object of class "performance"
Slot "x.name":
[1] "False positive rate"

Slot "y.name":
[1] "True positive rate"

Slot "alpha.name":
[1] "Cutoff"

Slot "x.values":
[[1]]
 [1] 0.0 0.0 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.6 0.8 0.8 1.0


Slot "y.values":
[[1]]
 [1] 0.0 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.8 0.8 1.0 1.0


Slot "alpha.values":
[[1]]
 [1]  Inf 0.98 0.94 0.86 0.74 0.73 0.64 0.53 0.39 0.34 0.31
plot(perf)
```

[image]

I am unsure of the output. And the ROC curve looks like a step function plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plot is just fine. After you run `prediction()` from the package ROCR you get an object, `pred`, with several components. Two of them are `pred$tp` and `pred$fp`, which represent the number of *true positives* and *false positives* respectively. To calculate the rate you divide them by the maximum, which is 5 in this case:

```
tpr <- pred$tp/max(pred$tp)
fpr <- pred$fp/max(pred$fp)

plot(fpr, tpr, type = "l")
```

These values are the same you get after running `performance(pred, "tpr", "fpr")`. Check the `x.values` and `y.values` components in `perf`. These are the values plotted with `plot(perf)`. You get an identical plot using `plot(fpr, tpr, type="l")`. The plots look like a step function because you only have five values.

---

**UPDATE**

It seems the structure of the object returned by `prediction()` has changed in recent `ROCR` versions. Now `prediction()` returns an S4 object, and so the information is stored in slots. This would be how the result from the OP data would look like now:

```
An object of class "prediction"
Slot "predictions":
[[1]]
 [1] 0.98 0.94 0.86 0.74 0.73 0.64 0.53 0.39 0.34 0.31


Slot "labels":
[[1]]
 [1] 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0
Levels: 0 < 1


Slot "cutoffs":
[[1]]
 [1]  Inf 0.98 0.94 0.86 0.74 0.73 0.64 0.53 0.39 0.34 0.31


Slot "fp":
[[1]]
 [1] 0 0 1 1 1 2 3 3 4 4 5


Slot "tp":
[[1]]
 [1] 0 1 1 2 3 3 3 4 4 5 5


Slot "tn":
[[1]]
 [1] 5 5 4 4 4 3 2 2 1 1 0


Slot "fn":
[[1]]
 [1] 5 4 4 3 2 2 2 1 1 0 0


Slot "n.pos":
[[1]]
[1] 5


Slot "n.neg":
[[1]]
[1] 5


Slot "n.pos.pred":
[[1]]
 [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10


Slot "n.neg.pred":
[[1]]
 [1] 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
```

Also, each slot is a list, I guess to potentially include several predictions together. The code in my original response should therefore be adapted to this new format. Something like this:

```
tpr <- pred@tp[[1]]/max(pred@tp[[1]])
fpr <- pred@fp[[1]]/max(pred@fp[[1]])

plot(fpr, tpr, type = "l")
```